# Redirecting to original URL for stateless session

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to create stateless security whereby a JWT token is stored in the Cookie instead of the SESSION.

The problem is that without a session the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is not aware of the original request (before the authentication page pops up). So at line [77 here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java#L77) savedRequest is null.

This seems weird and I guess I am doing something wrong.  How do I allow the page to redirect to the original URL requested after login for a stateless session?

1. I disable Sessions

   ```
       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

          ....formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)

       }
   ```
2. I then make a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler which extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.  I register this as the successHandler (above).

   ```
    @Component
    public class JwtCookieAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends 
             SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
       @Override
       public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
               throws IOException, ServletException {

           Cookie cookie = ... CREATE A COOKIE WITH A JWT

           response.addCookie(cookie);

           super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
       }

   }
   ```

EDIT:
This are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: HI did you find any solution? Same problem here :/

Answer (score 0):

In your configure, add :

```
.requestCache().requestCache(new CookieRequestCache())
```

Full exemple :

```
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/about").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/accounts").hasRole("ADMINISTRATOR")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .requestCache().requestCache(new CookieRequestCache())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                .and()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .securityContext()
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository);
```