# Spring security stateless redirect to original url issue

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, stateless

I'm using spring security oauth with stateless sessions. But my problem is the spring is using SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUESTS to save the source URL to which it has to redirect to after a successful login and it is maintained in the session. Since I m using stateless session I'm always being redirected to "/".

The same exact issue as in the post below
[Redirecting to original URL for stateless session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180747/redirecting-to-original-url-for-stateless-session)
Did anyone found a solution for this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by *after a successful login*? A login page? If you use no session, you can't use form login.

Comment: I m using EnableOAuth2SSO annotation which does the redirects to the authentication server where the user enters the credentials, and after successful validation it gets redirected back to the original URL.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find any solution?